# How can I split a string using regex to return a list of values?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I take the string `foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2` and return a collection with the values `1,5,2` in that order. I am looking for an answer using regex in C#. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you can use capturing groups

```
    private void RegexTest()
    {
        String input = "foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2";
        String pattern = @"foo\[\]=(\d+)";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) I modified your code a little using this regular expression "\\[\\]=(\w+)"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C#, but...

In java:

```
String[] nums = String.split(yourString, "&?foo[]");
```

The second argument in the `String.split()` method is a regex telling the method where to split the String.

Comment: This wont work in NET as split takes a literal string, not a regex

Answer (score 1):

Use the Regex.Split() method with an appropriate regex. This will split on parts of the string that match the regular expression and return the results as a string[].

Assuming you want all the values in your querystring without checking if they're numeric, (and without just matching on names like foo[]) you could use this: "&?[^&=]+="

```
string[] values = Regex.Split(“foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2”, "&?[^&=]+=");
```

Incidentally, if you're playing with regular expressions the site http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is fantastic (I'm just a fan).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this particular pattern:

```
string re = @"foo\[\]=(?<value>\d+)";
```

So something like (not tested):

```
Regex reValues = new Regex(re,RegexOptions.Compiled);
List<integer> values = new List<integer>();

foreach (Match m in reValues.Matches(...putInputStringHere...)
{
   values.Add((int) m.Groups("value").Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with numbers this pattern should match:

```
/=(\d+)&?/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex.Replace(s, !@"^[0-9]*$”, "");
```

Where s is your String where you want the numbers to be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to escape the ampersand like so:

```
/=(\d+)\&/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using the built-in string.Split function:

```
string x = "foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2";
string[] separator = new string[2] { "foo[]=", "&" };
string[] vals = x.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```