# RegEx "Split List"

Tags: c#, regex

I have this Regular Expression : `[E](((\d{1,2})))[-][E]?(\d{1,2})`
which I use on this string `S03E01-E03`

It works well.

When I use  [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5BE%5D(((%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)))%5B-%5D%5BE%5D%3F(%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)&i=S03E01-E03) to test my expression with they generate a "split list" how can this be done in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split a string using regex to return a list of values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93983/how-can-i-split-a-string-using-regex-to-return-a-list-of-values)

Comment: as an aside, you use a lot of useless symbols in your pattern: `E\d{1,2}-E?\d{1,2}` does exactly the same. No need to put everything in a character class or between parenthesis *(that creates useless capture groups)*.

Comment: No  E\d{1,2}-E?\d{1,2}  does not do the same because then I'll only get one group, but [E](\d{1,2})[-][E]?(\d{1,2}) does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Regex.Split()`.

```
string regex = @"[E](((\d{1,2})))[-][E]?(\d{1,2})";
string s = "S03E01-E03";

Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);

string[] splitResults = rgx.Split(s);

foreach (var str in splitResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Strange because, that was the first I Tried. But ofcause it works. (I'll accept you answer in 7 minutes)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    var regex = new Regex("[E](((\\d{1,2})))[-][E]?(\\d{1,2})");         
    var substrings = regex.Split("S03E01-E03");
```

that will split out your string into a String[].